# disable dynamic context menu using javascript in jsf

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2, primefaces, contextmenu

Is it possible to disable a dynamic context menu in JSF2.1 using java script ?

```
document.getElementById("myForm:contextMenuId:contextMenuItemId").style.display = 'none';
```

This works for a p:menuItem written as below.

```
 <p:contextMenu id="contextMenuId">                 
   <p:menuitem id="contextMenuItemId" value="Hi"></p:menuitem>
</p:contextMenu>
```

How can I perform something similar for the below written p:contextMenu(dynamic)

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextMenuId1" model="#{myBean.model}" ></p:contextMenu>
```

Comment: You can use jquery to code :)

Comment: No way to achieve this using the good old javascript ? :(

Comment: Primefaces component export all in div tag to client, in div tag, it have an ul tag, and ul tag have many li tag, so you can use Javascript too :)

Comment: Did you try to set id for menuitem in bean, and use your solution ?

Comment: I cant do that as the model can have any number of menuItems.

Comment: So what is the condition to disable menuitem ?

Comment: the context menu  is for a svg rectangle. so within the svg canvas, the context needs to be dsiabled outside the rectangle.

Comment: <p:contextMenu has 'for' attribute, did you try ?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, the for attribute can only refer to a JSF component ID. It wont work for SVG canvavs element IDs.

Comment: You can swap SVG canvas in <p:outputPanel, <p:outputPanel render div tag, so it will not affect you page.

Comment: I did not quite understand the last comment. Can you please explain what that means?

Comment: I will post as answer, comment is too small.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by clicking on a new p:contextMenu with rendered as false in all cases where i did not want to render the custom contextMenu. ( I couldnt find a better solution, but this should do for the teim being untill I can find a better way)

Comment: Your explanation is very bad

Answer (score 0):

You can swap svg in `<p:outputPanel`:

```
<h:form>
            <p:outputPanel id="test">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190">
                    <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
                             style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
                </svg>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:contextMenu for="test">  
                <p:menuitem value="Save" 
                            icon="ui-icon-disk"/>  
                <p:menuitem value="Update"

                            icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>  
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"  
                            ajax="false"/>  
                <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org"  
                            icon="ui-icon-extlink"/>  
            </p:contextMenu>  
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Yes. This is precisely the issue I am facing. if my SVG has another polygon and both have context menus with different menu items, how do i differentiate the target for the context menu ?

Comment: Sorry, i never combine html5 + primefaces. You need to post on Primefaces's forum :)